# "This time there is nothing unsafe about my footware"

Tags: meaning

What does this mean?

> ... and for all the safety critics out there **this time there is nothing unsafe about my footware**. —*from* [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SmWYw7c4DA&t=1m22s)

Comment: It's spelled _footwear_, because you _wear_ it. It's not related to "-ware" as in hardware and software, even though it sounds like it should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This time* suggests that the person in the video was previously criticized about wearing shoes that someone considered "unsafe" for working with tools. Here, he is making a joke: previously his shoes were unsafe, but now he's not wearing any shoes at all. Therefore, his shoes can't be unsafe, because they don't exist. (Of course, wearing no shoes at all when using tools is more dangerous than even wearing "unsafe" footwear, which he clearly knows—that's part of the joke.)

Comment: i understand the joke now, its funny